# Symfony2 - Profiler not pick up on details from Ajax requests

Tags: ajax, symfony

I'm using `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` to capture ajax requests from the browser in a Symfony2 project.  The actual requests work fine, unless there are any errors in my twig template being rendered, in which case nothing appears to happen in response.  Annoyingly, the Symfony2 Profiler doesn't show any information about the template that was supposed to be rendered - no details on the route that was matched, variable values, nor any database calls.

Can someone enlighten me as to why this is?

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem and only chrome browser could help me to find out the response error.
So do the following:

Firstly right click on the page on chrome and click inspect element

Secondly go to network tab and then find your ajax request to your server and click on that request chrome have a good feature that you could see the response in HTML this html response let you know your problem or error or what ever else that cause you do not get your needed response.
try this and let me know about your result?

Comment: Yes, that is what I've been doing.  Thanks.